# Get asynchron data from Service to Component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, asynchronous, service, components

i have a Workplaces Service which is fetching asynron data from an json file:

```
export class WorkplaceService{

    private allWorkplaces:Workplace[] = new Array();

    constructor(private http: Http){
        this.readWorkplaceDataFromFile().subscribe(data => this.allWorkplaces=data, error => console.log(error));
    }

    private readWorkplaceDataFromFile(): Observable<Workplace[]> {
         return this.http.get('assets/workplaces.json').map((response: Response) => {  
            return <Workplace[] > response.json()  
        }).catch(this.handleError);  
     }

    public getAllWorkplaces():Workplace[] {
        return this.allWorkplaces;
    }

}
```

Now i need to get this data into my WorkplacesComponent. I am trying this:

```
export class WorkplaceManagementComponent implements OnInit{

  allWorkplaces: Workplace[] = new Array();

  constructor(private storage: ProductionProgramStorage, private workplaces: WorkplaceService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.allWorkplaces = this.workplaces.getAllWorkplaces(); 

}
```

But as i do a asynchron http request, the data isn't loaded into my Service when my Component gets initilzied. How can i get the data from my Service? **I don't want to use subscribe() in my Component.** It should do my service.

Thanks.

Comment: Where in your service is the getAllWorkplaces function?

Comment: I edited my Question. Forgot it to put in.

Answer (score 0):

Try making allWorkplaces in the service public and accessing that. when you do the getAllWorkplaces() method it gives a snapshot of the object and in that point the assyncronous call may not have ended.

Comment: I have triedis this already, this doesn't work neither. The async call is still not ended..